# Values in Update query get entered into table as 0 or empty values

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax, sql-update

I have an HTML table with an Edit button that can be clicked which will allow a user to edit any `<td>` in the row. Once a user hits save, it then uses Ajax to send the values to `update.php` with all of the row info that is put into an update query. However, when the update query runs, all of the values except for 4 columns (species, container, mill, uom), get entered into the table in the DB either as `0` or are just blank. The column types where this is happening in the table are mostly `float(8)` with some being `nvarchar(255)`.

So it seems like the values are passing into `update.php` just fine so I am guessing that something might be wrong with my update query? Any advice would absolutely be appreciated on how I might be able to fix my update query issue to stop updating values to 0/blank to the actual values that are entered.

Javascript and Ajax (the names in quotes after the 'case' are the classes for the corresponding row:

```
var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    var elements = tds;
    var dict = {};
    var selected;
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();

      switch (type) {
        case "species":
          if (value) {
              dict["Species"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Species\n";
          }
          break;
        case "container":
          if (value) {
              dict["Container"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter Yes or No\n";
          }
          break;
        case "supp-name":
          if (value) {
              dict["Supplier Name"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Supplier Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "supp-sku":
          if (value) {
              dict["Supplier SKU"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Supplier SKU\n";
          }
          break;
        case "newsku":
          if (value) {
              dict["Current SKU"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Current SKU\n";
          }
          break;
        case "mill":
          if (value) {
              dict["Mill"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Mill\n";
          }
          break;
        case "lead-time":
          if (value) {
              dict["Lead Time"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Lead Time\n";
          }
          break;
        case "less-than-unit-cost":
          if (value) {
              dict["Less Than Unit Cost"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Less Than Unit Cost\n";
          }
          break;
        case "unit-cost":
          if (value) {
              dict["Unit Cost"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Unit Cost\n";
          }
          break;
        case "mill-direct-cost":
          if (value) {
              dict["Mill Direct Cost"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Mill Direct Cost\n";
          }
          break;
        case "unit-quantity":
          if (value) {
              dict["Unit Quantity"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Unit Quantity\n";
          }
          break;
        case "bundle-cost":
          if (value) {
              dict["Bundle Cost"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid number\n";
          }
          break;
        case "mixed-unit-price":
          if (value) {
              dict["6+ Mixed Unit Price"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid number\n";
          }
          break;
        case "uom":
          if (value) {
              dict["UOM"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid UOM\n";
          }
          break;
        case "mill-loc":
          if (value) {
              dict["Mill Location"] = value;
              break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Mill Location\n";
          }
          break;
        case "id":
              dict["ID"] = value;
              break;
        case "dropdown-select":
          var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
          selected = $row.find($(".selected")).val();
          console.log(selected);
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
        console.log(selected);
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dict, selected,
          success: function(data){
              console.log(dict);
              console.log(selected);
            }
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row updated");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to updated");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });
    }
```

Variables that bring in the value on `update.php`:

```
  $species = $_POST['Species'];
  $container = $_POST['Container'];
  $supp_name = $_POST['Supplier Name'];
  $supp_sku = $_POST['Supplier SKU'];
  $current_sku = $_POST['Current SKU'];
  $mill = $_POST['Mill'];
  $lead_time = $_POST['Lead Time'];
  $less_than_unit_cost = $_POST['Less Than Unit Cost'];
  $unit_cost = $_POST['Unit Cost'];
  $mill_direct_cost = $_POST['Mill Direct Cost'];
  $unit_quantity = $_POST['Unit Quantity'];
  $bundle_cost = $_POST['Bundle Cost'];
  $mixed_unit_price = $_POST['6+ Mixed Unit Price'];
  $uom = $_POST['UOM'];
  $mill_loc = $_POST['Mill Location'];
  $id = $_POST['ID'];
  $selected = $_POST['selected'];
```

Update query in `update.php`:

```
  $host="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  $sql = "UPDATE Example_Table SET [Species] = '$species', 
[Container] = '$container',
[Supplier Name] = '$supp_name',
[Supplier SKU] = '$supp_sku',
[Current SKU] = '$current_sku',
[Mill] = '$mill',
[Lead Time] = '$lead_time',
[Less Than Unit Cost] = '$less_than_unit_cost',
[Unit Cost] = '$unit_cost',
[Mill Direct Cost] = '$mill_direct_cost',
[Unit Quantity] = '$unit_quantity',
[Bundle Cost] = '$bundle_cost',
[6+ Mixed Unit Price] = '$mixed_unit_price',
[UOM] = '$uom',
[Mill Location] = '$mill_loc'

WHERE ID = $id";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Have you debugged using F12 tools to see that the names match?

Comment: I've been checking the console and receive no errors. I also have checked the network tab to look at my update.php after i save the row and it looks like all of the form data is getting passed to the page correctly.

Comment: Make sure that the places this is happening are not set into integers, meaning you may be trying to insert varchar in an integer field. You should also know that you can't have spaces in between your row names in the DB either replace the spaces with dashes `-` or underscores `_`

Comment: Try to avoid spaces in post variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS**

```
$species = $_POST['Species'];
$container = $_POST['Container'];
$supp_name = $_POST['Supplier Name'];
$supp_sku = $_POST['Supplier SKU'];
$current_sku = $_POST['Current SKU'];
$mill = $_POST['Mill'];
$lead_time = $_POST['Lead Time'];
$less_than_unit_cost = $_POST['Less Than Unit Cost'];
$unit_cost = $_POST['Unit Cost'];
$mill_direct_cost = $_POST['Mill Direct Cost'];
$unit_quantity = $_POST['Unit Quantity'];
$bundle_cost = $_POST['Bundle Cost'];
$mixed_unit_price = $_POST['6+ Mixed Unit Price'];
$uom = $_POST['UOM'];
$mill_loc = $_POST['Mill Location'];
$id = $_POST['ID'];
$selected = $_POST['selected'];

$host="xxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "UPDATE Example_Table SET [Species] = '$species', 
[Container] = '$container',
[Supplier Name] = '$supp_name',
[Supplier SKU] = '$supp_sku',
[Current SKU] = '$current_sku',
[Mill] = '$mill',
[Lead Time] = '$lead_time',
[Less Than Unit Cost] = '$less_than_unit_cost',
[Unit Cost] = '$unit_cost',
[Mill Direct Cost] = '$mill_direct_cost',
[Unit Quantity] = '$unit_quantity',
[Bundle Cost] = '$bundle_cost',
[6+ Mixed Unit Price] = '$mixed_unit_price',
[UOM] = '$uom',
[Mill Location] = '$mill_loc'

WHERE ID = $id";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);  
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo json_encode($result);
```

**SHOULD REALLY BE THIS**

```
<?php
    $species = $_POST['Species'];
    $container = $_POST['Container'];
    $supp_name = $_POST['Supplier_Name']; //make sure input names do not have spaces
    //ex: <input type="text" name="Supplier_Name" or name="Supplier-Name">, do this for every input that has space
    $supp_sku = $_POST['Supplier_SKU']; // or replace with `-`
    $current_sku = $_POST['Current_SKU'];// or replace with `-`
    $mill = $_POST['Mill'];
    $lead_time = $_POST['Lead_Time'];// or replace with `-`
    $less_than_unit_cost = $_POST['Less_Than_Unit_Cost'];// or replace with `-`
    $unit_cost = $_POST['Unit_Cost'];// or replace with `-`
    $mill_direct_cost = $_POST['Mill_Direct_Cost'];// or replace with `-`
    $unit_quantity = $_POST['Unit_Quantity'];// or replace with `-`
    $bundle_cost = $_POST['Bundle_Cost'];// or replace with `-`
    $mixed_unit_price = $_POST['6_Mixed_Unit_Price'];// This field remove the plus sign
    $uom = $_POST['UOM'];
    $mill_loc = $_POST['Mill Location'];// or replace with `-`
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    $selected = $_POST['selected'];
?>

<?php
    $host="xxxxxxx";
    $dbName="xxxx";
    $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxx";
    $dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sql = "UPDATE Example_Table SET [Species] = '$species', [Container] = '$container', 
    [Supplier_Name] = '$supp_name', [Supplier_SKU] = '$supp_sku',
    [Current_SKU] = '$current_sku', [Mill] = '$mill', [Lead_Time] = '$lead_time', 
    [Less_Than_Unit_Cost] = '$less_than_unit_cost', [Unit_Cost] = '$unit_cost', 
    [Mill Direct Cost] = '$mill_direct_cost', [Unit Quantity] = '$unit_quantity', 
    [Bundle Cost] = '$bundle_cost', [6+ Mixed Unit Price] = '$mixed_unit_price', 
    [UOM] = '$uom', [Mill_Location] = '$mill_loc' WHERE ID = '$id'";


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Yep, you were right...no spaces worked...i had thought I had done this before using columns with spaces but i guess not...thanks for the help!